# Check whether image exists on remote URL - iphone SDK3.0

Tags: iphone

In my iPhone I need to show a number of images from remote URL. Some of the URL may download some amount of data and but it may not contain actual image data. So what I need to do to check whether the downloaded data is an image data or not?

Thnx in advance,
Syam S

Comment: If you have solved the issue, could you post some code?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean that you're given **the actual URLs of the images** (e.g. http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png), and need to determine whether they're valid images, or do you mean that you're given **the URL of a page which may or may not contain images**?

Assuming the former (which seems more likely, and is easier than the other case), you'll want to look at the `Content-type` header returned by the server when you request the URL. Its value will generally be something self-explanatory, like `text/html`, `image/png`, `image/gif`, and so on. If you want image data, it should suffice to check whether the string starts with `image/` — although  you might want to refine that method if it turns out not to be accurate enough for your needs.

To get this header in an iPhone app, you'll probably want to use the methods described in Apple's [Communicating with HTTP Servers](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/CFHTTPTasks/CFHTTPTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001132-CH5-SW2) guide on their iPhone developer site. If you're only interested in the headers, you might consider using `CFReadStreamCreateForStreamedHTTPRequest` (instead of what the guide suggests, which is `CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest`) to read the response. This will avoid buffering all the response data, and will let you download what you need.